# How to convert the adc output of the capacitive soil humidity sensor v1.2 to actual humidity percentages in python(micropython)?

Tags: python, sensors, percentage, adc, micropython

Below is an example of a basic test code, from which you can read out the analog values of the sensor.
However, higher values are where the driest places are. Strictly water approaches value of 0. This is contrary to my basic knowledge of how moisture/humidity works - more water in the soil/air - more moisture/humidity.
What is the most efficient way to convert this into usable soil moisture percentages?

```py
from machine import Pin, ADC
from time import sleep
    
soil_moisture = ADC(Pin(34))
adc.width(ADC.WIDTH_12BIT)   # set 12 bit return values (returned range 0-4095)     
    
while True:
  soil_moisture_value = soil_moisture.read()
  print(soil_moisture_value)
  sleep(2)
```

Comment: I would think that what you are asking for would be provided by the maker of the sensor.  Is the proper term really "soil humidity"?  I thought humidity meant the amount of water in air.

Comment: No that was a braindead moment for me... I was meant to say soil moisture as you can see in the code.

Comment: Can you not just do MAX_SENSOR_VALUE - MEASURED_SENSOR_VALUE?

Comment: It didn’t take hardly any goggling for _capacitive soil sensor_  for the first result to be an article about the capacitive sensor and converting the output in three ranges. But feel free to try searching yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you use "[Capacitive Soil Moisture Sesnort 1.2](https://www.google.com/search?q=capacitive%20moisture%20sensor)"

This is the way how this sensor works: higher the raw value- lower the moisture. Go this way: measure raw value in water, then measure raw value in the air

Now you have value when it is wet you have value when its dry.

Then its just a math. Define following function:

```
def remap(value, leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax):
    # Figure out how 'wide' each range is
    leftSpan = leftMax - leftMin
    rightSpan = rightMax - rightMin
    # Convert the left range into a 0-1 range (float)
    valueScaled = float(value - leftMin) / float(leftSpan)
    # Convert the 0-1 range into a value in the right range.
    # return int(rightMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan))
    return rightMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan)
```

And somewehere in your code call this function:

```
moist_percent = remap(
    moistureADC.read(),
    1000, 2200,     # these values comes from experiment above when wet and dry
    100, 1
)
```

you have percentage value in variable

> moist_percent

Final app would be something like this:

```
from machine import Pin, ADC
from time import sleep
    
soil_moisture = ADC(Pin(34))
adc.width(ADC.WIDTH_12BIT)   # set 12 bit return values (returned range 0-4095)

def remap(value, leftMin, leftMax, rightMin, rightMax):
    leftSpan = leftMax - leftMin
    rightSpan = rightMax - rightMin
    valueScaled = float(value - leftMin) / float(leftSpan)
    return rightMin + (valueScaled * rightSpan)
    
while True:
    soil_moisture_value = remap(
        soil_moisture.read(),
        1000, 2200,     # these values comes from experiment above when wet and dry
        100, 1          # or you can map to whatever values you wish
    )
    print(soil_moisture_value)
    sleep(2)
```